# What should I do if I delete Main Camera in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm facing an odd bug in Unity - if I duplicate Main Camera and then delete the original, the new camera doesn't have the same perspective as the original.

Main Camera - 
[image]

New Camera (created via either duplication or by manually creating a Camera and copying properties) -

[image]

For reference, this is what the MoveCamera script looks like -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveCamera : MonoBehaviour {    

    public GameObject ballSphere;
    private Vector3 dist;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        dist = transform.position - ballSphere.transform.position;  
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.position = dist + ballSphere.transform.position;
    }
}
```

It simply asks the Camera to follow the sphere around.

When we duplicate the camera, the script doesn't work - the camera appears underneath the ball and doesn't follow it around. For reference, this is what it's supposed to look like -

[image]

This is what it ends up looking like (ball enters frame only after moving it forward [and appears to be above the camera]) -

[image]

Comment: Where's the script that duplicates the camera?

Comment: I just Right Click > Duplicate on the Main Camera.

Comment: Purely on speculation, what happens if you use `transform.position = ballSphere.transform.position - dist;` in your Update?

Comment: Just comment out the Start and Update and see what happens in that case